# jQuery Masonry in WordPress theme not working

Tags: wordpress, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to incorporate jQuery Masonry on my frontpage, but doesn't seem to load 4 out 5 times. If I click on my logo it seems to load, but if I refresh the browser it doesn't.

I'm enqueuing properly:

```
function my_scripts() {

  wp_register_script('jquery_masonry', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.masonry.min.js', array('jquery'), '2.0.110526' );
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery_masonry');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

then I have after wp_head in my header.php

```
   <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#boxes').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.brick',
        });
    });
  </script>
```

You can see the issue on my site: http://damoncook.net

Don't know what could be wrong as console isn't providing me with any info either. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Masonry seems to be loaded fine, as your divs are given masonry-brick classes. I get a js error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: sri_vars is not defined ' which is thrown from your c2ec16da.253941.js file. Perhaps thats the issue.

Comment: You're right, but when I went to turn of minify-ing to see what might be causing it I no longer get the error in console. Ugh.

Comment: Can you minify in stages, to see where the error is occurring. Sounds like your minifying is stripping out the sri_vars variable, or renaming it.